# I ran into kotlin version conflict with react native app

Tags: android, react-native, kotlin

hi I am new to react native, I have an app that was working pretty okay and today was working fine until I had a crash on some functionality I tried to remove node_modules package-lock.json and it got me very long error while trying to run the app again

```
npm run android
```

the error was basically these following lines repeated over and over again

```
e: /home/abdelhamied/work/personal/ghaith-app/node_modules/react-native-navigation/lib/android/app/src/reactNative63/java/com/reactnativenavigation/react/modal/ModalContentLayout.kt: (76, 28): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.16.
The class is loaded from /home/abdelhamied/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.5.30/d68efdea04955974ac1020f8f66ef8176bfbce1f/kotlin-stdlib-1.5.30.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
```

here is my `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        RNNKotlinVersion = "1.3.61"
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 30
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.61"
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

I tried to change kotlin version as I was searching throw the internet from 1.3.61 to 1.7.0 but it gave me conflicting kotlin version error do i need to do anything else?

that happened twice on 2 different devices (linux/windows) its working fine unitl I reinstall the node_modules folder

Comment: It come from node_modules `react-native-navigation` library you can remove the node_modules folder and re-install using  this command for remove `rm -rf node_modules` and run for install again `npm install`

Comment: tried that already. that what gave me the error at first place

Comment: `kotlinVersion = "1.5.31"` add this into buildscript -> ext if is not working then just chnages `kotlinVersion = "1.1.16"`